# ASPX with DNN: Line Break in Generated Souce Code

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

Utilizing ASPX and DotNetNuke - when viewing the generated source code all of our **META** calls in the XHTML document **HEAD** are showing up on one line.

Is there an easy way to force line breaks between each call in the *generated* source code?

I can use <%= System.Environment.NewLine %> in the BODY but not the HEAD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This could be for a number of reasons and honestly it doesn't really matter.  But you might check to see if you have the whitespace filter turned on in DNN as that will remove line breaks from the content.